# Minimizing Rg Plugins Popup

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Rg plugins popup to display the popup . I am having the functionality to minimize a popup. So when the user again clicks it will open in the same condition again that which was closed last time.

Can anybody help me out of this?

Comment: What do you mean by minimizing `popup`? And please show your code, what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ Денис Чорный  means when user taps on minimize icon it should be minimized and again than if it clicks it should open exactly at that state at which  it was last closed.

Comment: show your code, please. I misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: you can hide and show the popup without popping from the navigation t maintain the previous satate

Comment: @sudeshregmi hide and show on popup page is not working it is working on it's controls like in popup page I am having stacklayout at that it is hiding and showing but for whole popup it is not working.

Comment: you can save all your information in static variables needed for the popup and populate popup again with same static varaibles